# Capture image with python

Tags: python, image, opencv, camera

How can i capture the image using python?I am talking about capturing the image,not to save the particular frame of video.
normally we use  this to get picture.but it gives frame,not the image

```
while(True):
      ret, frame = cap.read()
      rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

      cv2.imshow('frame', rgb)
       if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       out = cv2.imwrite('capture.jpg', frame)
       break
```

Comment: What does this even mean? A frame is an image

Comment: when we open camera.camera has two option.either to take image or either to take video.when we capture image,it gives better result than any of particular video frame.

Comment: OpenCV doesn't have this functionality. You'll need to use a different library for full images, unfortunately. Note that this is partially due to OpenCV not implementing it, and partially due to the cameras abilities. Cameras have a reduced image size for video because there's throughput limitations; either it can capture video at 30 FPS (or whatever) at a smaller image size, or something like 3 a second (or whatever) at a larger image size. So if it's recording video, it can only take video frame-size snapshots. If you want to be able to take full images, you won't be able to have live video.

Comment: It's *possible* that your camera will let you set the frame size; you can try with e.g. `cap.set(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, frame_width)`. You can see all the options [on the docs for `VideoCapture.set()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html?#cv2.VideoCapture.set). Some cameras allow you to modify these, which may work for you, others may not.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done with [ecapture](https://pypi.org/project/ecapture/).

Ecapture can be installed by running `pip install ecapture` in the the cmd window

Code for capturing image.

```
from ecapture import ecapture as ec

ec.capture(0,"test","img.jpg")
```